# Get cart items and check for product of type X

Tags: 7, commerce

How do I?:

1. Get the current cart in commerce
2. For each item in the cart, check its product type?

I want to do the following:

```
foreach($cart_items as $item){
  if($item[product_type]=='X'){
    //perform a task
  }
}
```

I want to use this in the module code for a custom checkout pane.

Comment: when do you want to do this?  At checkout?  When an item is added to the cart?

Comment: @Chapabu When deciding what to render for the display of the custom pane. So within the module code for a custom pane in this case `checkout_pane_eventinfo_pane_checkout_form()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well this seems to work!

```
global $user;
$order = commerce_cart_order_load($user->uid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);

foreach ($wrapper->commerce_line_items as $delta => $line_item_wrapper) {                                  
  $type = $line_item_wrapper->commerce_product->value()->type;   
  if($type=='X'){
    //perform a task
  }
}
```